# Multiple answers

Tags: discussion

So I got multiple answers to a question, from what I can tell they are all good answers but offer different routes to the solution so is it wrong to mark all of them as the right answer and can that even be done?

Comment: You can only mark *one* as the best. Your other option is to not mark any, you are free to do so.

Answer (score 8):

It cannot be done. There can only be one (accepted answer).

The criteria you should use is - which answer most helped you personally.

If you want to reward the other good answer, upvote them.